# How to Upgrade Setup file without deleting Compact Sql DB

Tags: windows-installer, sql-server-ce

I have deployed a windows setup file with compact SQL db (local database). Now I want to upgrade the setup file without deleting the existing local database.

Could anyone help me how I can proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without knowing how your current installer is authored but basically consider the following points:

1) If you are doing Major Upgrades, where is your RemoveExistingProducts scheduled?  Be careful you aren't asking the installer to do a full uninstall / reinstall as you'd get the database file reinstalled.

2) Take a look at the Component element's NeverOverwrite attribute.

3) Also consider the Component element's Permenant attribute  if you'd like the SDF to remain on uninstall  so that subsequent reinstall will have the same data.

Comment: My question is how i can implement it in future... Is there any step by step guide available?

Comment: All i need is start up guide... any help on this?

Comment: Thought visual studio is the only option....After seeing your profile, i am realizing there is a world for Windows Installer:) Downloading WIX straight away.. Hoping the best

Comment: Thanks i just changed permanent attribute.. Its working fine... I have a doubt, what if i modify a column in particular table of sdf file.. Is that possible to upgrade or i have to install completely.

Comment: In this story, the database is just a file to the installer. It won't "upgrade" it.  What you probably need to do is have the installer lay down a "stock" database file and have the application clone it as user data on first run.  Then during upgrades the installer overwrites the stock database and on next run the application compares schemas and then takes action needed to upgrade the user database.

Comment: Could you please explain how application compares schemas and then takes action needed to upgrade the user database? Sounds new  to me..I thought its manual process

Comment: You'd have to program your application to do this.